# In ConfigParser, why lines start with `REM ` will be ignored?

Tags: python, config

The codes are like this:

```
        if line.split(None, 1)[0].lower() == 'rem' and line[0] in "rR":
            # no leading whitespace
            continue
```

I think this means if I write a config like this:

```
[memo]
rem ember_last = True
```

The line starts with `rem ember_last` will be ignored.
Why was the ConfigParser  designed like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`rem`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490986.aspx) in Batch is used to add comments, i.e. it’s a command that essentially does nothing. It seems that this decision was carried over to configuration files:

> Enables you to include comments (remarks) in a batch file or in your configuration files.

However, `rem` and the actual comments are always separated by whitespace so it makes no sense that a configuration option `remember` would be ignored (only `rem ember` would). The code you posted confirms this, as the following shows:

```
>>> line = 'remember_last = True'
>>> line.split(None, 1)[0].lower()
'remember_last'
```

So, your problems seems to be something else.

Answer (score 1):

It's a little bit influenced by the programming language BASIC. `REM` means Remarks and introduce a comment. Also `comment` should be recognized as a comment. The other comment statements are `#` and `;`.

Answer (score 0):

Small experiment:

```
In [190]: line = 'remember_last = True'

In [191]: line.split(None, 1)[0].lower() == 'rem' and line[0] in "rR"
Out[191]: False
```

shows that your concerns are unfounded. Do you need an explanation - or you may figure it out by yourself?

PS second part of boolean the expression is absolutely redundant

Comment: *“second part of boolean the expression is absolutely redundant”* – not if the line starts with whitespace.

Comment: @poke Are you sure?!

*In [192]: '   This line starts with whitespace'.split(None, 1)
Out[192]: ['This', 'line starts with whitespace']*

Line should not start with whitespace in config file?!

Comment: Yes, the split will eliminate whitespace at the beginning, hence `line[0]` will check it again, to make sure that the line actually starts with `rem` and not some whitespace.

Comment: Lines of configuration files are not supposed to have leading spaces. If a line has a leading whitespace - it is malformed configuration file.

Comment: Well, I was solely argumenting based on that code. You said the second part is redundant, and I gave you an example where it isn’t. Also Python’s config parser supports leading spaces just fine, as do [others](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INI_file#Whitespace).